# Converting column to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have written following query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Category) AS Categories,
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Order Number]) AS Orders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Product) AS Products
FROM
    Associate
```

and the output is as follows

```
Categories    Orders     Products
---------------------------------
   17         13050        37
```

But I want result like this

```
#Object#    |   #Count#
------------+-----------
Categories  |     17
Orders      |  13050
Products    |     37
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Simple count with group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` or unpivot the result:

```
with c as (
      select count(distinct Category) AS Categories,
             count(distinct [Order Number]) AS Orders,
             count(distinct Product) AS Products
      from Associate 
     )
select v.*
from c cross apply
     (values ('Categories', Categories),
             ('Orders', Orders),
             ('Products', Products)
     ) v(which, cnt);
```

This would normally be the most efficient choice.  However, `count(distinct)` is rather expensive, so three scans of the table might not be a big performance hit.  So:

```
select 'Categories' as which, count(distinct Category) as cnt
from Associate union all
select 'Orders', count(distinct [Order Number])
from Associate union all
select 'Products', count(distinct Product);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both the queries helped